# Test Coverage Calculation For JRuby Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, code-coverage

I'm looking for a tool to generate code coverage statistics for my JRuby-backed Rails application. I've looked into things like [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov), but they don't seem to support JRuby. As far as I can see, none of the 'common' libraries support JRuby. I haven't been able to find any good tools to do this for me.

I am using Rails 3.1.3 with Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with current JRuby coverage lib: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6106.

As the issue status states it is fixed in JRuby 1.7, which is currently in RC stage and will be out very soon.